# Should relative paths in shell scripts start with a dot?

Tags: shell, path

I often see, and have somewhat adopted myself, to precede relative paths with `./` in shell scripts. But is there situation where

`source ./foo/helper.sh`

and

`source foo/helper.sh`

would actually yield different results? Is there any rational for this "convention"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
source ./foo/helper.sh
source   foo/helper.sh
```

Those two should be equivalent. But these two aren't, not in Bash anyway:

```
source ./helper.sh
source   helper.sh
```

The reason is that for a plain filename, `source` would look at the directories in `$PATH` first, but for a filename containing a slash, that doesn't happen. If there's a `helper.sh` both in the current directory and in `$PATH`, the first one will find the former, and the second will find the latter.

Similar considerations may apply for other programs, so writing `./foo` instead of `foo` makes it explicit you mean a file in the current directory, not one possibly looked up through some other means.

Comment: And there's this known issue of `-file` vs `./-file`. Although `source` or `.` supports no options, in some shells it complains about `-f` being an invalid option instead of not trying to interpret its arguments as options in the first place.